# Инициализация плагина с параметром

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! На сайте используется javascript плагин, позволяющий перетаскивать элементы списка. Он нормально подключается и работает. Но теперь возникла необходимость иногда при ajax обновлении части страницы инициализировать плагин, используя параметр. Вот код инициализации:

```
    $("#all_packages_ul_"+PACKAGING_ID_GLOB).dragsort({ dragSelector: "div", dragEnd: saveOrder_packages_6, placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>"

вместо 6 должно тоже стоять выражение из переменной PACKAGING_ID_GLOB, не знаю как его туда подставить и возможно ли это, т.е. динамически формировать название функции
```

Comment: У вас по окончанию события 'drag' вызывается функция saveOrder_packages_6(), правильно я понимаю? Т.е. существуют функции saveOrder_packages_1(), saveOrder_packages_2()... и так со всеми значениями PACKAGING_ID_GLOB?

Comment: да, всё правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно ничего формировать. В функцию `dragEnd` передается указатель на перетащенный элемент. Id элемента должен быть уникален во всем документе. Думаю подойдет что-нибудь подобное

```
$('ul.package').dragsort(dragSelector:'li',dragEnd:save_order);

function save_order(el)
{
   //el - перетащенный элемент
   //$(el).parent().attr('id') - id контейнера (ul)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как в функцию dragEnd передать указатель на перемещенный элемент?